# Adding WDS client to wireless network causes routers to stop responding

Tags: openwrt, wds

OpenWRT 18.06.0

I am trying to create a WDS bridged network using two Linksys 1900ACS routers. I have followed the instructions found at the bottom of https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/network/wifi/atheroswds (section "Luci" and lower)

The steps are quite simple but the minute I add the "Client (WDS)" to the client router, suddenly both routers slow to a crawl and basically stop responding. I am guessing that I created some sort of endless loop between the two routers, but it's not clear to me what I did wrong. Again, the steps seems pretty simple.

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Is there another tutorial for getting this done? Ideally a video that shows the configuration of *both* routers, not just the client?

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. When you have 2+ routers and each has 2+ wireless bands (e.g. one is 2.4Ghz, the other is 5Ghz) then the LAN interface -> Physical Settings on all routers must have "Enable STP" checked. I am theorizing that some sort of network loop occurs because there are 2+ paths into each router. If there was a single wireless band this probably wouldn't be a problem.

Again, this is a guess but ever since I enabled STP on the routers the problem went away.